# How to Always Emulate Touch Events in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I just update Chrome to v29.0.1547.57 and turning on 'Emulate Touch Events' (DevTools-->Overrides-->Emulate Touch Events) is no longer saved when I exit tabs. I exclusively work on mobile development and it is going to be a major pain if I now have to manually turn on touch emulation every time I open DevTools. I've looked through all of the extension API and DevTools documentation and found nothing. Does anyone know how I can always Emulate Touch Events when DevTools are open?

[EDIT]
This is not an issue in Chrome Canary (v31). It looks like it was [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175966#c13) back in July. I've been having some other issues with the current Canary build, though, so I would still like to be able to emulate touch events in the current stable build.

Comment: found [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496393/overrides-page-in-chrome-developer-tools-gone-in-latest-canary) very helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can start Chrome with `--simulate-touch-screen-with-mouse` which was recently renamed from `--emulate-touch-events`. [How to use these command line flags](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)

Unfortunately there is no way to persist the touch event emulation across restarts at the moment.

Comment: The flag you mention doesn't seem to do anything but make all pages unresponsive (including the built-in chrome pages like apps and dev-tools). I tried also adding the --touch-events flag to no avail. Is there another flag(s) that I should be using in addition to the one you mention?

Comment: @jam i can repro the problem you mention. Looks broken, and I'm not sure what the solution is yet.

Comment: --simulate-touch-screen-with-mouse is still not working

Comment: I am guessing that touch emulation is not available in chrome apps either. Am I right? Or is there a special flag/manifest file entry / unicorn tear that would enable touch emulation for chrome apps?

Comment: Any news on this issue? Would like to simulate touch in "kiosk mode".

Comment: Is there a to move it to `chrome://flags/`? Macbook is very annoying not to support that.

Answer (score 3):

chrome://flags

look for **Enable touch events**

Comment: This is not the same since you don't get the draggable "fluid" scroll behavior, what you get when enabling touch emulation in the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but as I found it on google and there is no answer I thou'g I'd add one.

currently setting the `--touch-devices` flag on chrome start up set chrome up to fire touch events on devices.

N.b. I am working on a touch screen device using touch enabled monitors and a packaged chrome app. Setting this flag in the start up config allows `touchstart`, `touchend` etc to be fired.