# Chrome settings - set "emulate touch events" as default settings

Tags: google-chrome, emulation

We are trying to run some automated tests (coded ui based) on our mobile application via Chrome browser.
In order to make the tests available to run, we must set the browser to work as 'emulate touch events'. 
The thing is that as part of our test flow, a new chrome browser is being launched on each test but the definition is gone.

I already check this one, but it doesn't work:
[How to Always Emulate Touch Events in Chrome Dev Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366332/how-to-always-emulate-touch-events-in-chrome-dev-tools)

Any other suggestions?

Thanks,
Yair

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the dev tools window must be opened for the overrides to kick in, have you tried that?