# Overrides page in Chrome Developer Tools gone in latest Canary

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome (version 32.0.1677.0 canary Aura), I can't find the overrides tab/page in the Developer Tools settings. (It used to be placed between the "General" and "Workspace" tabs. Did they move it, or did I forget to enable something?

Comment: Feel free to star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345477

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the console drawer, then you can open the Sensors tab via the drawer menu on the left.

[image]

Sensors provides geolocation and accelerometer settings.

Additionally, the newer [Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/) captures the basics of mobile device emulation.

[image]

Comment: On `32.0.1684.0 canary` it is now named "Emulation" and you can only see it if you open the console panel as a split view of another panel (elements, network...)

Comment: I'm on v32 and unable to get Emulation even by trying above steps, any pointers ?

Comment: It seems like a bug to me, but I got it by first hiding the console, and then going to `View -> Developer -> Developer Tools` (note: *not* the console). The key is to open the tools that way, or it was for me... I'm having some wonkiness using the javascript console since switching to chrome 32.

edit: err, on retest that doesn't quite work so well either. What works for me now is selecting the 'element' view and then clicking the split pane icon: http://i.imgur.com/upRDDZW.png

Comment: @swajak +1 for split pane icon!

Comment: important note : when you try to show the brawler, do not stay on console tab.

Comment: Thanks guys. I added a note about console tab and the split pane icon. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a great workaround for setting the geolocation of an immobile desktop machine. This solution only works while dev tools is open. There's also a Chrome extension called "Manual Geolocation" that's more user-friendly.

Comment: Lots of cool advanced features in the emulation tab its missing the simple ability to resize the inner window like you do on Firefox. I want to easily test all widths not just fixed width devices.

Comment: Overrides is no longer in under settings. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509865/no-overrides-page-in-chrome-dev-tools-settings helped me to figure out where to actually find "Emulation" menu. You need to resize the window to be able to visualize it.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like the "Emulation" button only is available from Console, when Console is opened from one of the other tool tabs. Ex. "Source" or "Elements".

Go to "Elements" , click on the "Show console" icon. The "console drawer" will open in bottom part of the window with Console, Search, Emulation tabs. If this is a bug or not is hard to say.

Comment: You can also hit Esc in Dev Tools for bottom Console drawer to slide up open.

Comment: Yeah, I spent like 5 minutes trying to find this drawer... :(

Comment: Version 35 is like this.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is quite old and everything is now changed with the new "device mode". You cannot use any of this anymore.

As stated here by @paul-irish (from the Chrome DevTools team) [on twitter](https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/766577165714403328) :

- one should just activate the device mode, and then use the shift key + drag the mouse around to emulate pinch zoom, with no particular setup.

[image: How to activate device mode]

- this pinch to zoom emulation **doesn't seem to work very good with JS libs like Hammer**.

For now, it is better to test pinch to zoom on actual devices, or with http://browserstack.com