# New Chrome Dev Tools: Geolocation Override

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, google-chrome-devtools, development-environment

Chrome updated their dev tools a few days ago. I've spent the best part of an hour looking for the geolocation override in Chrome but can't find it. They don't seem to have updated their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#device-geolocation-overrides) either. I'm on my Mac if the layout is different.

It used to be located here:
[image]

Does anyone know if there is still an geolocation tool in dev tools or has this feature been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question for how to get to the Emulation tab: [Overrides page in Chrome Developer Tools gone in latest Canary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496393/overrides-page-in-chrome-developer-tools-gone-in-latest-canary)

Once there, you can find Geolocation overrides in the Sensors pane.

Comment: I followed this procedure, but there is no sensors pane.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override the geolocation by using this extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-geolocation/njjpmclekpigefnogajiknnheheacoaj