# No "overrides" page in chrome dev tools settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How can I enable the overrides panel in my settings? I opened my Chrome and it's just gone, I've wasted most of my day trying to get this to work, but 0 answers on Google.

Thanks Chrome, just make my settings disappear, cool!

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Emulation panel is the new Overrides pane

[image]

Comment: does multitouch emulation just not work with a touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

The Overrides have been moved to the slide out tabs that you can access by pressing Esc on any  panel.

You will find the settings you are looking for under the Emulation tab there.

Comment: on chrome 54 the tab is now called 'sensors'