# Geolocation not working on mobile browsers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-devtools, geocoding

I have just finished my project that uses Google Maps API. when I tested on my mobile it failed. I started debugging and it seems to be having problems getting the current position

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ ... }, function(error){ ... }):
```

This line fails on Chrome and default browser, the callback function is never called (and I don't know how to see what error is thrown).

So I started using the Chrome emulator ( [Refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509865/no-overrides-page-in-chrome-dev-tools-settings) ) and no error is being triggered. Everything works well.

And I am passing a second function to handle errors to getCurrentPosition and nothing is displayed... what would be the problem?! Do you know what can I do to make it work on my mobile? Any other test I can do?

- I tested on different computers and it works
- The settings allow me to share my current position

Comment: Any live URL to share? Complete code?

Comment: Try Chrome Web Tools and remote debugging to view errors in mobile Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: @mmocny You just beat me to it by seconds!

Comment: The obvious question: is 'location services' enabled on your mobile?  If not, the error function won't be fired as there has not been a geo-location error.